# Read response metadata headers with grpc interceptor and add values to HttpContext

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, grpc

I have two services, one REST api witch communicates with another service using grpc.

Trying to read the response metadata headers in the REST api with an grpc interceptor and set the values in the http response headers. It works fine for most of the request but sometimes it fails due to that the HttpContext is null. Probably because the http request already responded so the HttpContext no longer exists.

Can this be the case and can it be solved in another way?

```
public class SetHeaderInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
    public SetHeaderInterceptor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }
    public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
        AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        var call = continuation(request, context);
        var response = new AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse>(call.ResponseAsync, HandleHeader<Metadata>(call.ResponseHeadersAsync), call.GetStatus, call.GetTrailers, call.Dispose);
        return response;
    }

    private async Task<Metadata> HandleHeader<TResponse>(Task<Metadata> responseHeadersAsync)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await responseHeadersAsync;
            string header = response.GetValue("HeaderKey");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
            {
                if (_httpContext?.HttpContext?.Request != null)
                {
                    _httpContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("HeaderKey", header);
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
        catch (RpcException ex)
        {
            return default;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in general, I wouldn't recommend the pattern of mixing HttpContext and gRPC's API for metadata, because they operate at different levels of abstractions. Also from your example is not clear what your code snippet is supposed to do. Looks like you're getting ResponseHeaders from a call and you're trying to add the apply one specific key to the HttpContext but it's unclear how the HttpContext relates to the rest of your code.

Comment: Simply I just want to pass the same header in the grpc response to the http response in the rest api. This header value comes with every response from the grpc service so I want to do this in an interceptor/middleware instead of handle the response in every call to the grpc service. Do you have another proposal on how to do this?